# How do I export text messages from android into iphone

Tags: iphone, data-transfer, sms, android

When moving back from Android to iPhone, I'm unable to transfer my text messages with the "move to iOS" app.

About half my text messages are missing for some reason.

I'm looking for an alternative method (either an application, or steps to do by hand). In regards to application, I am specifically looking for something that not sketchy (eg. dr. fone, or the rebrands of such app).

Ideally something open source or provided by a reputable company.

I've attempted to move messages over by editing the backups sqlite database file, however upon restoration, itunes thinks the backup is corrupted and refuses to restore it.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

1. Method for saving text only: similar to the "move to iOS" app, but still requires a complete application-SMS Backup +. It also transfers text messages, but it cannot be added to iPhone Messager or iMessages.
   Here are the steps: Log in to Gmail on Android> Settings> Forwarding and POP / IMAP> Enable IMAP> Enable IMAP> Download SMS Backup from the Google Play Store +> Launch the application> Connect to Gmail> Backup SMS to your Google> On iPhone login Gmail> Done.
2. Method for saving text and merging with iPhone Messager: It is recommended to use transfer tool to convert the file to a format supported by iOS.

The above information is from [this article](https://www.fonecope.com/transfer-text-messages-from-android-to-iphone.html), it also mentions the comparison of several methods.

Comment: If it `cannot be added to iPhone Messages or iMessages`, then it doesn't work. Transferring them to email, or creating a stitched together images of all pages of a text history and saving the non-Messages format to the iPhone is not the same. When I used "Samsung Smart Switch" to transfer EVERYTHING from my iPhone 4 to a Galaxy S9, everything transferred **perfectly**.  Now I'm trying to transfer everything back, plus years more of text messages to an iPhone 12.  It's laughable how BAD "Move to iOS" is.  Transferring parts of message histories is simply unacceptable.